# Jasmine + Karma + Istanbul testing: self and/or window is undefined

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node, karma-coverage

I am working with a project that needs to be tested (unit testing). Jasmine is already working fine however, we need a coverage.

Searched about it and Jasmine + Karma + Istanbul can do the work.

I am struggling with the complications between Karma (browser/client) and node (server-side). The fs, logger (log4js) node modules and the major one is the self and window.

Already managed to solve or ignore the two node modules (fs and logger) by using browserify and by removing logger (or switching it to console.log when testing).

So, for my problem (undefined window or self), here's the error message when I run **"npm test"**:

```
09 05 2018 14:14:07.047:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
 ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\kyl.sanantonio@awsys-i.com\workspace\TougouBaseline_Call\karma.conf.js:15:21)
    at Object.parseConfig (C:\Users\kyl.sanantonio@awsys-i.com\workspace\TougouBaseline_Call\node_modules\karma\lib\config.js:410:5)
    at new Server (C:\Users\kyl.sanantonio@awsys-i.com\workspace\TougouBaseline_Call\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:56:20)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\kyl.sanantonio@awsys-i.com\workspace\TougouBaseline_Call\node_modules\karma\lib\cli.js:280:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kyl.sanantonio@awsys-i.com\workspace\TougouBaseline_Call\node_modules\karma\bin\karma:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "----",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": ".mongorc.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server.js",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test1": "jasmine-node spec"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.15.3",
    "ws": "3.0.0",
    "compression": "1.6.2",
    "body-parser": "1.17.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "express-session": "1.15.3",
    "connect-mongo": "1.3.2",
    "method-override": "2.3.9",
    "multer": "1.3.0",
    "diskspace": "2.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "encoding-japanese": "1.0.23",
    "lockfile": "1.0.1",
    "log4js": "0.6.8",
    "async": "0.2.10",
    "mongoose": "3.6.11",
    "moment": "2.10.6",
    "rmdir": "1.2.0",
    "log4js-extend": "0.1.2",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-contextmenu": "2.6.3",
    "autosize": "4.0.0",
    "request-ip": "2.0.2",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "log4js-node": "0.1.2"
  },
  "author": "---",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.7",
    "browserify": "^16.2.0",
    "browserify-fs": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.9.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-node": "^1.14.5",
    "jsdom": "^11.10.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-global-preprocessor": "0.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jsdom-launcher": "^6.1.3",
    "watchify": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {

    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],
        files: [
            'spec/serverLineSpec.js',
            // 'spec/*.js',
            'serverLine.js'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'serverLine.js': ['coverage', 'browserify']
        },
        globals: {
            'self': window
        },
        target: "web",
        plugins: [
            require('browserify'),
            require('karma-browserify'),
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('karma-global-preprocessor'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('browserify-fs')
        ],
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
        port: 9878,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        autowatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome', 'Chrome_without_security'],
        customLaunchers: {
          Chrome_without_security: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            flags: ['--disable-web-security']
          }
        },
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        coverageReporter: {
            includeAllSources: true,
            dir: 'coverage/',
            reporters: [
                { type: "html", subdir: "html" },
                { type: 'text-summary' }
            ]
        },
        browserify: {
            debug: true
        },
        webpack: { node: { fs: 'empty', } }
    });
};
```

**And when I use:**

```
globals: {
            'self': global.window
        },
```

Error message is:
**self is not defined**

**test/serverLineSpec.js**

```
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var https = require("https");
var settings = require("../settingsServer.js");
var serverLine = require("../serverLine.js");
var webRTCLib = require("../webrtc.io");
// HTTPSサーバ
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync("system/newkey.pem");
var certificate = fs.readFileSync("system/newcert.pem");
var passphrase = settings.getServerPassphrase();
var options = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    passphrase: passphrase
};
var app = express();
var port = Number(settings.getPortNumber());

var mockData = JSON.parse("{\"room\":\"servlet\",\"caller\":\"102\",\"callee\":[102],\"callerUsername\":\"s1\"}");

function MockSocket(socketId) {
    this.id = socketId;
    this.data = "";
    this.send = function(data, cb) {
        this.data = data;
        cb = cb || function() {};
        cb();
    };
}


var httpsServer;
var webRTC;

describe("Test call_user event", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);

        // WebSocketサーバ
        webRTC = webRTCLib.listen(httpsServer);
        serverLine.initialize(webRTC);

        webRTC.rtc.rooms[""] = [];
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds[""] = [];
        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"] = [];
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"] = [];
        webRTC.rtc.sockets = [];
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        httpsServer.close();
    });

    it("test user is not found", function() {

        var mockSocket = new MockSocket("laksdlaks");

        webRTC.rtc.fire("call_user", mockData, mockSocket);

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(mockSocket.data);
        expect(jsonData.eventName).toMatch("receive_call_user");
        expect(jsonData.data.userFound[0].status).toBe(false);
        expect(jsonData.data.userFound[0].userKind).toMatch("102");

    });

    it("test user found", function() {

        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"].push("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"].push("102_servlet");


        var mockUserSocket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockUserSocket);

        var mockSocket = new MockSocket("testSocket");

        webRTC.rtc.fire("call_user", mockData, mockSocket);

        var callUserJson = JSON.parse(mockUserSocket.data);
        var rcvCallUserJson = JSON.parse(mockSocket.data);

        expect(callUserJson.eventName).toMatch("call_user");
        expect(callUserJson.data.roomid).toMatch("servlet");
        expect(callUserJson.data.caller).toMatch("102");
        expect(callUserJson.data.callerUsername).toMatch("s1");

        expect(rcvCallUserJson.eventName).toMatch("receive_call_user");
        expect(rcvCallUserJson.data.userFound[0].status).toBe(true);
        expect(rcvCallUserJson.data.userFound[0].userKind).toMatch("102");
    });
});

describe("Test response_call_user event", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);

        // WebSocketサーバ
        webRTC = webRTCLib.listen(httpsServer);
        serverLine.initialize(webRTC);

        webRTC.rtc.rooms[""] = [];
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds[""] = [];
        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"] = [];
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"] = [];
        webRTC.rtc.sockets = [];
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        httpsServer.close();
    });

    it("test decline call response", function() {

        var mockDataResponse = JSON.parse("{\"accept_call\":\"false\",\"callee\":\"105_servlet\",\"caller\":\"101\"}");

        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"].push("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"].push("105_servlet");

        var mockUserSocket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockUserSocket);

        webRTC.rtc.rooms[""].push("sampleSocketId2");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds[""].push(101);

        var mockSocket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId2");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockSocket);

        webRTC.rtc.fire("response_call_user", mockDataResponse, mockSocket);

        var rcvRspCallUserJson = JSON.parse(mockSocket.data);

        expect(rcvRspCallUserJson.eventName).toMatch("response_call_user");
        expect(rcvRspCallUserJson.data.accept_call).toBe("false");
        expect(rcvRspCallUserJson.data.caller).toMatch("101");
        expect(rcvRspCallUserJson.data.callee).toMatch("105_servlet");

    });

    it("test accept call response", function() {
        var mockDataResponse = JSON.parse("{\"accept_call\":\"true\",\"callee\":\"105_servlet\",\"caller\":\"101\"}");

        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"].push("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"].push("105_servlet");

        var mockUserSocket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockUserSocket);

        webRTC.rtc.rooms[""].push("sampleSocketId2");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds[""].push(101);

        var mockSocket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId2");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockSocket);

        webRTC.rtc.fire("response_call_user", mockDataResponse, mockSocket);

        var rcvRspCallUserJson = JSON.parse(mockSocket.data);

        expect(rcvRspCallUserJson.eventName).toMatch("response_call_user");
        expect(rcvRspCallUserJson.data.accept_call).toBe("true");
        expect(rcvRspCallUserJson.data.caller).toMatch("101");
        expect(rcvRspCallUserJson.data.callee).toMatch("105_servlet");

    });

    it("test calling of multiple users (2 online, 1 offline)", function() {
        var mockDataResponse = JSON.parse("{\"room\":\"servlet\",\"caller\":\"102\",\"callee\":[105, 106, 107],\"callerUsername\":\"s1\"}");
        var expectedStat = [true, true, false];

        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"].push("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"].push("105_servlet");

        var mockCallee1Socket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockCallee1Socket);

        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"].push("sampleSocketId2");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"].push("106_servlet");

        var mockCallee2Socket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId2");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockCallee2Socket);

        var mockSocket = new MockSocket("testSocket");

        webRTC.rtc.fire("call_user", mockDataResponse, mockSocket);

        var rcvCallUserJson = JSON.parse(mockSocket.data);

        var calleeArray = mockDataResponse.callee;
        for (var i = 0; i < calleeArray.length; i++) {
            expect(rcvCallUserJson.eventName).toMatch("receive_call_user");
            expect(rcvCallUserJson.data.userFound[i].status).toBe(expectedStat[i]);
            expect(rcvCallUserJson.data.userFound[i].userKind).toMatch(calleeArray[i]);
        }

    });

    it("test calling of multiple users (3 online)", function() {
        var mockDataResponse = JSON.parse("{\"room\":\"servlet\",\"caller\":\"102\",\"callee\":[105, 106, 107],\"callerUsername\":\"s1\"}");
        var expectedStat = [true, true, true];

        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"].push("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"].push("105_servlet");

        var mockCallee1Socket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId1");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockCallee1Socket);

        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"].push("sampleSocketId2");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"].push("106_servlet");

        var mockCallee2Socket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId2");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockCallee2Socket);

        webRTC.rtc.rooms["servlet"].push("sampleSocketId3");
        webRTC.rtc.userKinds["servlet"].push("107_servlet");

        var mockCallee3Socket = new MockSocket("sampleSocketId3");
        webRTC.rtc.sockets.push(mockCallee3Socket);

        var mockSocket = new MockSocket("testSocket");

        webRTC.rtc.fire("call_user", mockDataResponse, mockSocket);

        var rcvCallUserJson = JSON.parse(mockSocket.data);

        var calleeArray = mockDataResponse.callee;
        for (var i = 0; i < calleeArray.length; i++) {
            expect(rcvCallUserJson.eventName).toMatch("receive_call_user");
            expect(rcvCallUserJson.data.userFound[i].status).toBe(expectedStat[i]);
            expect(rcvCallUserJson.data.userFound[i].userKind).toMatch(calleeArray[i]);
        }

    });
});
```

**Already tried the following:**

1. Including a javascript with global variable/s -- still undefined (As
   I think it loads the file before running the spec)
2. following this: https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-istanbul-with-jasmine/index.html -- No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information

Comment: You don't need Karma in this case. You can just use Jasmine & Istanbul to get coverage reports. I have done that before. You cab refer this article: https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-istanbul-with-jasmine/index.html

Comment: @Vivasaayi already tried that but I'm having this error: No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information

Comment: @Vivasaayi -updated my post, I included the spec.js.

Comment: @Vivasaayi - already solved it by using the direct path of the node module.

Comment: If this is solved, please add an answer below. Comments are just for clarification of a post.